# Using find with grep not isolating files

Tags: regex, grep, find

I have a sequence of files that look like this:

```
image-seq 2020-04-13-05-50-00.jpg 
image-seq 2020-04-13-06-00-00.jpg
...
image-seq 2020-04-13-16-50-00.jpg
image-seq 2020-04-13-17-00-00.jpg
```

I'm trying to separate files with times from 17:00 until 05:50 the following day (so only the first and last filenames in the example should be returned). I thought I could use find with grep to isolate the files and then `mv` them, but files which shouldn't appear show up in the resulting output.

I'm using macOS grep, so I'm not sure if that's the issue.

The command I tried was:

```
find . -type f -name \*.jpg -exec grep -E '\-1[7-9]|2[0-3]|0[0-5]-\d{2}-\d{2}\.jpg' {} \;
```

I'm not sure what I've done incorrectly, but if you have any tips that'd be great.

Comment: `grep` searches the files' *contents*, not their names; you want the `-regex` option to `find` (but note that it looks for matches to the entire path, including "./" at the beginning).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Interesting, i thought grep could find filesnames also, good to know! So I just need to include that with the find and I'm all set? Thanks!

Comment: `grep` can find filenames, but only if you format a list of filenames *as a file*, and tell it to search that. Which you could do with something like `find ... -print | grep 'somepattern'` (note that in this case, the file of filenames isn't stored as a disk file, it's passed straight from `find`'s output to `grep`'s input via the pipe). But `find ... -exec grep ...` passes the filenames to `grep` *as arguments*, which means that `grep` will interpret them as names of files that it should search the contents of.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS `find` you may use this command to get your matching files using `-E` and `-iregex` options:

```sh
find -E . -iregex '.*(-1[7-9]|2[0-3]|0[0-5])(-[0-9]{2}){2}\.jpg'

./image-seq 2020-04-13-05-50-00.jpg
./image-seq 2020-04-13-17-00-00.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching *inside* the files using `-exec grep` search inside the list of *filenames* printed by `find` using a pipe `find | grep`.

Then, you also have to adapt the regex. With `-a|b|c-` you search for either `-a`, `b`, or `c-`. You probably meant `-(a|b|c)-` which searches for either `-a-`, `-b-`, or `-c-`.

```
find . -type f -name \*.jpg | grep -E -e'-(1[7-9]|2[0-3]|0[0-5])-..-..\.jpg'
```

However, writing regexes for fitlering number ranges is tiring and error prone. As you probably know, above regex doesn't check the minutes. You might want to switch to `awk` instead:

```
find . -type f -name \*.jpg | awk -F- '$5>=17 || $5<5 || $5==5 && $6<=50'
```

Comment: Thank you, It works well, but I had to add an escape in the regex `\-(1...` otherwise i get `grep: invalid option -- (`

Comment: The `awk` is interesting also... thank you

Comment: Glad to hear. Thank you for the feedback. The correct way to escape a leading `-` in `grep` is `-e`.